# Coda 2 show matching opening/closing tag?

Tags: tags, text-editor, coda

I was wondering is there a way in Coda 2 to display the opening/closing tag when on the line of it?

For example if I am on the line which contains < div>

Is there a way I can get Coda to highlight which is the < /div>?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

this is the most updated version https://github.com/emmetio/Emmet.codaplugin

Answer (score 1):

If you install the TEA plugin you can use control-b to match the element.  It highlights the whole selection to the closing tag.

http://onecrayon.com/tea/coda/

Works in Coda 2.

Comment: The author is no longer supporting Coda 2, but suggests another project; and THAT project was replaced with: https://github.com/emmetio/Emmet.codaplugin

Answer (score 0):

~/Library/Applications/Support/Coda 2/Plug-ins/ does not work after running it.

no such file or directory